# value binding inside Visual Studio Code markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I am trying to document some of my working processes using .md files inside visual studio code.

In some cases some code that I want to display could depend on a variable such as a project name.
I can document this using:

````
```bash
mkdir {projectName}
mkdir {projectName}/app
mkdir {projectName}/doc
```
````

and I also found that I could use HTML to display a text input

```
   <input name="projectName" value="{projectName}"></input>
```

I hoped that I could replace the {projectName}'s with spans that have a common name and use a simple script block for handling the onChange event of the input to replace what is displayed in the spans with the inputs updated value but this is being blocked as potentially dangerous code.

The target is obviously to have a way to quickly customize the scripts and make them usable in the next project.

While writing the Q I realized that for scripts I should probably generalize the scripts using environment variables instead of the above way but the need for customization of this sort is also relevant for example for .yaml files for which which I can not use this workaround.

looking for any ideas on how to author and display .md documents with placeholders being replaced by variable strings (preferably from within the text itself).
if variables could depend on previous variables that would be even better but not a strict requirement.

Thanks

Comment: you don't necessarily need environment variables. shell variables are a thing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @starball. I was not aware of the difference. did some quick reading and now I am a bit more informed.